# How to insert some link in js for double quotation singe quotation issue?

Tags: javascript

```
echo'<script>
$( ".callback" ).click(function() {
  waitingDialog.show("Loading Something...",{
                progressType: "success",
                onHide: function () {alert("<a href="">link</a>");}
      });
setTimeout(function () {
  waitingDialog.hide();
}, 3000);
});
</script>
';
```

I want insert some link in

```
alert("<a href="">link</a>");
```

My `echo` is single quoted. So how I use it? When I tried with `.$pp.` variable I  got an error saying

> Unexpected EOF

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape quotes inside a string.

```
onHide: function () {alert("<a href=\'http://example.com\'>link</a>");}
                                    ^^                  ^^
```

Comment: don't understand give a example please dear

Comment: I've updaetd my answer, added example.com link. Just put inside escaped quotes.

Comment: i used as you say

Comment: @AnanyaSharma: sure, it's in alert, it can't be clickable. I've just make your code working (without escaping there was a PHP fatal error).

Comment: how a put some link in alert or anyway how it do?

Comment: @AnanyaSharma: not possible to put clickable link into alert. Use modals, create own popup (`position: fixed; top: 50%; width: 50%; width: 200px; height: 200px; margin: -100px 0 0 -100px`) or something, there is more options. Alert isn't the right way.

Comment: i know that possible with modal, but i want first process bar come animate then couple hidden link comes for downloading..

Comment: @AnanyaSharma: it's irrelevant. You any HTML markup you need instead of `alert` in the same place. `onHide: function() {var div = document.createElement("div"); div.innerHTML = "<a href=\'http://example.com\'>link</a>"; div.className = "popupDiv"; ...}` and add CSS I've put above to `.popupDiv`. For example.

Comment: after click button progress bar come animate then gone but no html link box coming i cret a popupDiv but same result

Comment: .popupDiv{width: 100%;
        padding: 50px 0;
        text-align: center;
        background-color: lightblue;
        margin-top:20px;
    }

Answer (score 0):

```
echo'<script>
  $( ".callback" ).click(function() {
    waitingDialog.show("Loading Something...",{
                  progressType: "success",
                  onHide: function () {
                     alert("<a href=\"http://yourlink.com\">link</a>");
                  }
        });
    setTimeout(function () {
      waitingDialog.hide();
    }, 3000);
  });
</script>
';
```